# In MySQL, How can get the intersection of the 9 select results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making the sql code. I have met the barrier, that is, so many select sentences in SQL query. Finally I want to get to the intersection of 9 select results

My sql code is same as below, just 1 select sentence. 8 select sentences are different from only search word, eg) cholera, diarrhea, fever, vomit, nausea, etc

First select sentence. Don't be suprised. That code is simple and repeatedly.

```
 (SELECT code_co.code, code_co.disease_co, code_en.disease_en
 FROM code_co
 LEFT JOIN code_en ON code_en.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN note ON note.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN inclusion ON inclusion.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN exclusion ON exclusion.code = code_co.code
 LEFT JOIN ds ON code_co.code = ds.code
 LEFT JOIN tx ON code_co.code = tx.code
 LEFT JOIN sx ON code_co.code = sx.code

 WHERE 
  note LIKE CONCAT(  '%', (
  SELECT ds_word.ds_en
  FROM ds_word
  WHERE ds_co LIKE  '%cholera%'
  LIMIT 0 , 1
  ),  '%' ) 
  or
  ds_content LIKE CONCAT(  '%', (
  SELECT ds_word.ds_en
  FROM ds_word
  WHERE ds_co LIKE  '%cholera%'
  LIMIT 0 , 1
  ),  '%' ) 
  ...
  inclusion LIKE CONCAT(  '%', (
  SELECT ds_word.ds_en
  FROM ds_word
  WHERE ds_co LIKE  '%cholera%'
  LIMIT 0 , 1
  ),  '%' ) 
  )
```

Below is the captured picture on phpmyadmin.

[image]
Really working code!
And 2nd select sentence is same as first sentence except cholera. Cholera is my search word. 
In this way, I have 9 select sentences. 
I want to get the intersection, but in MySQL, How can I care? 
Intersect or minus can be used in just 2 sentences. (Right?)

(1st select sentence)
intersect
(2nd select sentence)
intersect
(3rd select sentence)
...
This way is right?

Please help me. 
Thank you for your advice

Comment: This sounds like a bad, non-performant way to go.  You need a parser/indexer, not SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the "intersect" by using `and` in the `where` clause.  Using `or` is equivalent to a "union".

Also, you can simplify your expression by doing:

```
LEFT JOIN sx ON code_co.code = sx.code
CROSS JOIN (SELECT concat('%', ds_word.ds_en, '%') as pattern
            FROM ds_word
            WHERE ds_co LIKE  '%cholera%'
            LIMIT 0 , 1
           ) const
WHERE note LIKE const.pattern and
      ds_content like const.pattern and
      . . .
```

Comment: Gordon, Thank you for your wise code. Due to your cross join code, I decrease my codes greatly.

Comment: `intersect` is a keyword that works on the results of subqueries (such as `union` and `union all`).  It does not go in a `where` clause.